# Phone blocks call from someone who is not on the block list

Tags: call-screening

I hope I am posting in the right section.
I would like to ask support from you to solve an issue with my Samsung A325F/DS (android version: 13). The phone is not rooted.

The issue is: the phone blocks all calls from my wife despite her number is not listed on the block list. Actually, there are not people on the list of blocked contacts. The problem occured first on 3rd June and it is persistent. I have tried the following:

- restarted phone: still blocked
- put her number to the block list and remove: still blocked
- remove her contact and then readd: still blocked
- asked her to call me on the other SIM: still blocked
- replaced Samsung's phone app with Google's phone app: still blocked
- turned off spam filtering: still blocked

Text messages do come through from her. I can call her without any problems. No other numbers are blocked. I am contemplating to try factory reset, but I would like explore other options if you have any ideas.

Thank you very much in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved: it was ESET Security that put some numbers on the block list.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We really appreciate anyone who finds the solution by themselves! Perhaps you could explain more about how this happened and how to prevent it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).